# Is it dangerous to eat the contents of a damaged can?

Tags: nutrition

I have been told that eating food from a can that has been damaged (e.g. from falling) is dangerous, even if the damage is just a dent. Nobody is able to explain me why though so I am not convinced. My reasoning would be that as long as no air can get inside the can, the food is safe.

Comment: Could you please define damaged - mechanically deformed or no longer hermetic? In the first case there are no good reasons to be inedible. In the second there is risk of contamination and spoilage.

Comment: I understand that some cans are lined with BPA. I don't see any answers yet that discuss the possibility of a damaged BPA lining contaminating the food.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Damage to a can, including dents, can be a sign of [Botulism contamination](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/help/faqs_hotline_preparation/index.asp).  Even a tiny amount of botulinum toxin can be [lethal](http://www.medicinenet.com/botulism/page2.htm#3howserious).

> NEVER USE food from containers that show possible "botulism" warnings: leaking, bulging, or badly dented cans; cracked jars or jars with loose or bulging lids; canned food with a foul odor; or any container that spurts liquid when opening. DON'T TASTE SUCH FOOD! Even a minuscule amount of botulinum toxin can be deadly.

However, dents by themselves are [not necessarily dangerous](http://eatrightli.org/documents/education/safety%20of%20canned%20goods%20handout.pdf).  While they can make the can more susceptible to rust, which can allow in air, which can then result in bacterial contamination, so long as the can is still sealed a recent dent is not likely to be a problem.

Comment: +1 The with a new dent is the dent may have created tiny openings you cannot see that make the can no longer safe.    If you drop a can you are about to use and dent it, it is probably safe to open up and eat.  But if you store it over time bacteria can potentially get into the tiny openings and contaminate the food.  It may be unlikely but with the risks you point out being so high is it really worth it.

Comment: I’m baffled by this warning: On the one hand, the FSIS is probably a *very* reputable organisation. On the other hand, *C. botulinum* is an anaerobic bacterium … as a consequence, leaking (= open) cans are a clear indication that there is *no* danger from botulism, since the oxygen would have killed any bacteria, and nor does the bacterium produce gas that may cause such leakage by pressure damaging the can.

Comment: @kon: what's dangerous about C. botulinum is the toxins it produces. They may stay in the can even after the bacterium is long gone.

Comment: @Sklivvz True. But I fail to see how a leakage is indication of such a contamination. For *other* bacteria, this is cogent (leakage = container no longer provides isolation). For *C. botulinum*, however, it isn’t.

Comment: @Konrad the spores of C. botulinum can survive in oxygen environments, I believe. Once the spores reach suitable  anaerobic areas (which can [include](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09305.html) food systems or even wounds where oxygen is seemingly abundant), they begin to grow and form the toxins. A liquid environment can form a barrier to oxygen, allowing the bacteria to grow within the food itself (but the area directly exposed to air would not be habitable to the bacteria).

Comment: @kon, I think the reasoning is: unsafe container/sterilization => risk of botulinum (and other problems). The point here is that botulinum cannot be excluded once you are not sure about the can.

Comment: Thanks for this anwer. The reason why I asked is because I recently bought a can with a dent in it. I only noticed when I got home. Probably somebody in the shop dropped it and put it back on the shelve. When I got home I noticed the dent. My girlfriend insisted on just eating it, but I remembered people saying you shouldn't eat from damaged cans. Judging on your answer I guess it would not be harmful because the dent is probably very recent and not that bad.

Comment: @Konrad - The contamination may not (You might even go to is probably not I do not know the incidence of botulism) but C. botulinum but there are so many bacteria that make you sick that it is not safe.  Food must either be kept hot or cold or in a sterile enviornment to prevent the growth of bacteria.  Once the can is broken open then bacteria can get in and contaminate the food.  A good number of them can kill besides just botulinum

Comment: @Chad All that is besides the point since the warning was explicitly about *C. botulinum*. Beofett’s explanation probably comes closest to the real reason.

Comment: @BaGi: How would you know how recent the dent is?

Comment: @Oddthinking: I don;t know for sure, but the can comes from a store where they sell very large volumes every day. They constantly need to refill the store. I assume that the can was damaged either:
- by myself when loading it in the cart or the trunk of our car
- by a previous customer that dropped it on the floor, put it back and took another one.
Of course there is a chance that the can was damaged before, e.g. at the factory, but even then... when you look at the production date (the date the food was put into the can), it's not that long ago.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are two different risks: 1) if a can sitting on a shelf *spontaneously* bulges or dents over time, this might be a result ofC. botulinum anaerobically propagating inside the can and producing toxics. Note that such dents and bulges don't *normally* allow air in. 2) if a can has suffered a major dent from a fall, this *could* cause rust which *could* allow air in, and other, aerobic pathogens could develop.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If the can is leaking that might be due to internal pressure caused by bacterial growth--and the growth probably came before the leak.

Answer (score 9):

The point about sealed but distorted cans is that an anaerobic bacterium (such as *Clostridium botulinum*) may have produced gases inside the can, and it may have been the pressure of these gases which have caused the distortion to the can.

So the problem here is not the dent allowing contamination (you should in any case avoid cans where the seal has been broken) but the possibility that the contamination caused dents.

Hence the advice in this [U.S. Department of Agriculture endorsed leaflet](http://eatrightli.org/documents/education/safety%20of%20canned%20goods%20handout.pdf) to check for bloating and bulges, to test cans to see if they "pop" back after applying pressure to the dent, and most importantly to avoid those which spray or explode on opening.   In other cases, it says "eating from dented cans is not unsafe".